# Почему в Windows при запуске исполняемого файла, написанного на си+gtk, запускается консоль?

Tags: c, windows, консоль, gtk3

Создал файл main.c. Его содержимое:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Компилирую с помощью команды:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

Получаю файл main.exe. При двойном клике на этот файл вместе с окном программы запускается окно консоли. Как сделать, чтобы окно консоли не запускалось?

[image: В Windows]

В Linux такого не происходит. В нём запускается только окно программы.

[image: В Linux]

Comment: опция для линкера -mwindows

Comment: Спасибо! Предполагал, что дело в компиляции, но не знал, как правильно задать поисковый запрос в google.